# How to reset the target runtime from commandline

Tags: .net-core

I've got a project which contains:

```
<RuntimeIdentifier>win7-x86</RuntimeIdentifier>
```

in the `csproj`. Is there an option which cancels it in `dotnet publish/build`?

I do not want to modify the `csproj` if possible. I don't want to select a specific runtime either. I'm after the default behaviour when the runtime is not specified at all. (using framework-dependent deploy)

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish?tabs=netcore21) don't list anything obvious.

Answer (score 1):

You can unset the runtime by specifying an empty string and unsetting the `self-contained` option:

```
dotnet publish --self-contained=False -r ""
```